# Phonegap textarea, selection arrow in a wrong position

Tags: cordova, cursor, textarea

While using a textarea to edit some texts, the text cursor and the selection arrow get desynchronized when a word collides with the end of the editable area.

I'm using android 2.3.6 for testing.

When I add some more pixels to the textarea width it fixes the problem, but then I get the same issue in other line. I also tried adding some padding and I got the same result.

I think the problem is the selection arrow, it needs to fit inside the textarea.

Any ideas on what to do? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: it's a simple textarea, with a fixed width. I removed everything else to test it